# Rails3: how do I set the root of my app to application#index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have `views/application/index.html.erb`

and in my routes file I have:

```
  root :to => "application#index"
```

And my ApplicationController is as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
    # ask whether teh player wants to go first or second
    @player_start_character = ""

      end
end
```

but when I nav to localhost:3000 it still says the "you have just started a rails app project" page

I also have deleted public/index.html

Comment: what do you see when you do "rake routes"?

Comment: rake routes shows nothing... =( just the path to my app on the file system

Comment: This should work. Restart the server and try again to be sure!

Comment: restarted server... same problem. Does rails not like the application controller rendering views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to remove the /public/index.html file

Comment: I have, I forget to mention it, but it is gone.

Comment: nope... my IDE shows it gone... but it is still in the file system... well this is embarrassing.

Comment: the real problem was that Aptana copied the entire project, rather than just linking to all the files.